# How to check if data is already in MySQL DB with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check if the user's data is not already in use before creating the account on my website.

What I tried (code below) was make a query to each data that has to be unique (email and phone) but thing started getting slow.

Here is the code that I tried to use:

```
$email_amount = $connection->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = \'' . $email . '\'')->num_rows;
$phone_amount = $connection->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone = \'' . $phone . '\'')->num_rows;

if ($email_amount > 0) {
    echo '<script>showError(\'ERRROR: EMAIL ALREADY IN USE!\')</script>';
    return;
}
if ($phone_amount > 0) {
    echo '<script>showError(\'ERRROR: PHONE ALREADY IN USE!\')</script>';
    return;
}
```

Before making this query, I have to make another query to create the user's unique ID. I'm using this code for that:

```
$id = $connection->query('SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC');
$id = $id->fetch_assoc()['id'] + 1;
```

For last but not least, to connect to the DB, I'm using the following code (it's on another file outside `public_html`. I used `require_once` within the function that I make the queries above):

```
<?php
function db_connect() {

    static $connection;


    if(!isset($connection)) {

        $config = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
        $connection = mysqli_connect($config['host'],$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
    }

    if($connection === false) {
        return mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    return $connection;
}

$connection = db_connect();

if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}


?>
```

So after all this background, the actual question: is there a better way to check if the data is not already in the DB?

I'm willing to give any aditional information if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to have unique entries by email or other column, the best would be to create a unique index on this columns.

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD UNIQUE INDEX <index_name>;
```

Why this is better:
In your code you can get a race condition e.g. 2 or more requests at the same time can produce duplicates in your table.

Comment: Right but you didn't explain why.. unique indexes will prevent a hard to debug possible condition which is called a race condition

Comment: I will do some search on that, thanks! Do you know what does it return if the data is not unique?

Comment: The insert statement will simply fail with `Duplicate entry ..` error. You should rely only on a success state e.g. `mysqli_query` returns `true` and if needed `mysqli_insert_id`.